# $Pr(b)$ as a function of $x,y$ only

Tags: probability

Note: Usual probability rules hold, we can even consider $a,b,\lnot b$ to be $A,B,B^c$ if that makes it better.

Given that $Pr(a|b)=x$, and $Pr(a)=y$ what's $Pr(\lnot b)$, in this case, if it's easier, we can get $Pr(b)$, deriving former is trivial.

What I have so far,

$\frac{Pr(a \land b)}{Pr(b)}=\frac{Pr(b|a)Pr(a)}{Pr(b)}=Pr(a|b)$

We can multiply $Pr(b)$ and divide $Pr(a|b)$ to get:

$\frac{Pr(a\land b)}{Pr(a|b)}=\frac {Pr(b|a)Pr(a)}{Pr(a|b)}=Pr(b)$

All help appreciated.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a value for $Pr(a \land b)$, which is just $Pr(a\cap b)$, since I don't know if $a$ and $b$ are independent. Anyway to get rid of $Pr(a \land b)$.

Do we get something tidy with the assumption $a$ and $b$ are independent?

Comment: I don't think this can be done without additional conditions. If it was possible, it would also work in the case where $a$ and $b$ are independent (which also means $x=y$). However, in this case $Pr(b)$ can be anywhere between $0$ and $1$. You can possibly derive some *bounds* for $Pr(b)$ but not the actual value.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?  Is it possible that you have misinterpreted the problem or accidentally omitted pertinent information?